# How do I create a Before Update trigger to only update based on certain conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a before update trigger I'd like to do so that "Update CustomersTable set LastPurchase = ### where CustomerName = "Abc" only runs when a specific condition in the table is met.

I know this one has to be a Before Trigger. The problem I have is that all the examples I see, show how to run this trigger if it's based on a condition not being met where it then gives an error message. I want it to run so that when it meets my conditions, it runs the update.

> before update on CustomersTable
>
> for each row
>
> begin
>
> declare variable;
>
> select whatever into variable from CustomersTable where
>
> code
>
> if code
>
> then

....

> end if;

Comment: So the unedited error and the complete trigger.

Comment: Unless you're needing to look at rows from CustomersTable other than the one being updated, you should probably just use `OLD.` and `NEW.` to reference the fields' values.